# How to merge 2 arrays field and combine as 1 object (kev value) in document in Mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, aggregation-framework

I have 2 different arrays in 1 document and I need to combine both arrays as 1 object as keys and values. 
Both arrays have exact number of value.

Original document

```
{ 
"case_number" : "123", 
"questions" : [ "Primary Organ Site","Date of Diagnosis" ],
"answers"   : [ "Uterus", "12/12/2017"]
}
```

I want them to combine into this

```
{ 
"case_number" : "123", 
"result" : { 
    "Primary Organ Site": "Uterus",
    "Date of Diagnosis": "12/12/2017" 
    }
}
```

I already tried this

```
db.cases.aggregate(
  "case_number" : true,
  "results": {
     "$arrayToObject" : {       
        $map: {
          input: "$answers",
          as: "answer",
          in: [ "$questions" , "$$answer" ]  
        }
      }
    }
)
```

and many more others.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Solve the answer

```
db.cases.aggregate(
  "case_number" : true,   
  "results": {  
     $arrayToObject: {
        $map: {
          input: "$answers",
          as: "answer",
          in: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$questions", { "$indexOfArray" : [ "$answers", "$$answer" ] } ] },  "$$answer" ]

        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: This does work :) 
Have a question though, where did you find u can pass an array to `in` field of `$map` operator? There are no such definitions on MongoDB docs!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Mongo 3.6)

```
db.cases.aggregate([{ "$project": { "result": { "$concatArrays": [ "$questions", "$answers" ] }, "case_number":1 }}])
```

Comment: Tnx but not working, it just combined both arrays but not as key value

Comment: @Garciano this is the result. **"results" : [ "Primary Organ Site","Date of Diagnosis","Uterus", "12/12/2017" ]** any thoughts?

Comment: add the properties that you want in the project stage. Answer updated